# Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'WebGrease, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

Estou apenas abrindo um novo projeto basedo em MVC 5, framework 4.0, c#, e após abrir o projeto pela primeira vez e compilar, ocorre o erro

```
Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'WebGrease, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ou uma de suas dependências. A definição do manifesto do assembly localizado não corresponde à referência do assembly. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Qualquer projeto novo que crio não compila e acusa esse erro no browser. Não instalei nenhum componente.

No meu `web.config` está assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication1-20150730092912.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication1-20150730092912;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Experimentou tirar o último `<dependentAssembly>` da configuração?

Comment: Já passei por esse erro e percebi que era DLL sendo referenciada errada no Web.Conf.

Comment: Eu atualizei esse webgrease para a versão 1.5 e continua dando erro. Agora do Owin

Comment: Se você não instalou nada, porque tem essa referência no `webconfig`? Tire de lá. Se atualizou, deve ter instalado.

Comment: O webgrase aparece na criação de um projeto novo, e também aparece nas referencias

Comment: Sozinho não aparece. Fez o que eu falei? Qual o resultado?

Comment: Fiz, e removi as referencias. Ao criar o novo projeto já estava trazendo algumas referencias que não era para trazer. o erro continua.

Comment: Qual é o erro do OWIN?

Comment: Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ou uma de suas dependências. A definição do manifesto do assembly localizado não corresponde à referência do assembly. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: E você tentou atualizá-lo também?

Comment: Sim removi ele das referencias e instalei novamente.

Comment: Resolvi!!! A solução foi ir em Import and Export Settings, e dar um Reset all settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolvi!!! A solução foi ir em Import and Export Settings, e dar um Reset all settings

Answer (score 2):

Reinstale o WebGrease com uma versão mais atual. Abra o Package Manager Console (View > Other Windows > Package Manager Console) e use o seguinte comando:

```
Update-Package WebGrease
```

Esta versão 1.3.0.0 é muito antiga. Deve ser dos tempos do MVC4.